# Regular expression,

Tags: regular-language

[image]

Question 23: The string zyyzy belong to the language, right?

Answer (score 1):

$zyyzy$ does belong to the language but not $zyyxz$

Edit : in $zyyzy$ can be split into two : $zyy$ and $zy$ which both belongs to $zy^*$ and therefore $zyyzy$ belongs to $(x^*y|zy^*)^*$

Comment: Can you help the OP with a "brief justification"?

Comment: @EthanBolker I thought that OP was just asking for a confirmation but I added the explanation anyway